# Replace token in text file with content from another text file in MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild

I have 2 **MULTILINE** text files, I want to combine them into a third file in an Msbuild script.

Ideally, I would have a token in one file, say %REPLACEME%, somewhere in the middle of that file, and I would want it replaced with the contents of the 2nd file (which contain multiple lines of text).

I want to do this in MSBUILD, although a Windows Shell solution would suffice, and so would the usage of some 3rd party utility (preferably small, and a single exe).

The solution is trivial if the content of the replacement text file is just one line .. but that is not the case.

Note that I want to AVOID using Powershell, I also want to avoid building my own MsBuild Tasks.

Thanks

Comment: What version of MSBuild are you using?

Comment: 3.5 though I would consider 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MsBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) which have a RegexReplace task. I use it for my builds without any problem

Comment: Also, look at the "TemplateFile" task in the MSBuild Community Tasks.